# Return a single row when more than two columns have the same value

Tags: mysql

I need to return just one row when I have two or more equals rows with same values in two specifics columns. The select row must be the latest in column DATE.

```
SELECT * FROM `history` WHERE productId IN (166, 2915) ORDER BY history.value;
```

OBS: For productId, I can have more than 20 items. It is just only example.

ACTUAL RETURN

| id | supermarketId | productId | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2722 | 2 | 2915 | 7.98 | 2023-11-19 00:00:00 |
| 180 | 3 | 166 | 7.99 | 2023-07-23 00:00:00 |
| 1639 | 2 | 166 | 8.98 | 2023-06-05 00:00:00 |
| 4251 | 2 | 166 | 8.98 | 2024-02-17 00:00:00 |
| 4220 | 2 | 2915 | 8.98 | 2024-02-17 00:00:00 |
| 2759 | 3 | 2915 | 9.99 | 2023-11-15 00:00:00 |

DESIRED RETURN

| id | supermarketId | productId | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 180 | 3 | 166 | 7.99 | 2023-07-23 00:00:00 |
| 4251 | 2 | 166 | 8.98 | 2024-02-17 00:00:00 |
| 4220 | 2 | 2915 | 8.98 | 2024-02-17 00:00:00 |
| 2759 | 3 | 2915 | 9.99 | 2023-11-15 00:00:00 |

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `history` WHERE productId IN (166, 2915) 
AND date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM history) ORDER BY history.value;
```

But some rows were eliminated:

| id | supermarketId | productId | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4251 | 2 | 166 | 8.98 | 2024-02-17 00:00:00 |
| 4220 | 2 | 2915 | 8.98 | 2024-02-17 00:00:00 |

Comment: For that, you're probably looking for GROUP BY statement. You can group by a single field, but also multiple fields.
SELECT * FROM history WHERE productId IN (166, 2915) GROUP BY productId, supermarketId ORDER BY date DESC;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, then following query should solve the problem

```
SELECT A.* FROM [history] A
INNER JOIN (SELECT [productId], supermarketId, MAX(date) as date
            FROM [history]
            GROUP BY [productId], supermarketId
    
            HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1 and productId in (2915, 166)) as B
ON A.[productId] = B.[productId] AND A.supermarketId = B.supermarketId and A.date = b.date
```

Comment: What's the `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1` used for ?

Comment: as I understood based on data you have provided, you want to include unique values and values which are duplicated but the lattest one

Comment: Run very well !! First create a "table A" and "Table B", but B with the mean columns. Second, the INNER JOIN return only values where the columns from A and B are the same. Is it run like this? English is not my native lenguage, so, sorry.

Comment: it does not create a table, it just select table and add alias

Answer (score 0):

first,check your id format,then use between 166 and 2915

Comment: please can you provide more information for example providing the code sample that successfully implements the `between 166 and 2915`